# Combine BLUP estimate for mulitple variables in R lmer()

Tags: r, export-to-excel, lme4

Any help on how to combine the output of ranef() for multiple variables together for export into excel

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on SO.

Comment: Dear Fola, Could you post some code or porblems did you have as well as more info on your expected output. At the current state of your question it is quite difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLConnect` package to save the output of `ranef` of `lme4` package into Excel file. Please see below an example:

```
#simulation of data
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
rr1 <- ranef(fm1, condVar = TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(rr1$Subject)

#writing to xls file
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("ranef_res.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, "ranef")
writeWorksheet(wb, df, "ranef")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```